# i am not able find dynamic element in android app

Tags: dynamic, find, appium, element

[image: App ScreenSHOT]

i have dynamic elements in my android app and there is nothing to find it out .Please check screen shot of my app and attributes and let me how can we do it.

I have tried with the given attributes

I just want ti find these elements and send keys

Answer (score 0):

Try find element by `xpath` with this value:

```
//*[contains(@class,'android.widget.EditText')]
```

It will return the first element if there are many elements with same class.

If you want other element with class `EditText`, you can add count like this:

```
(//*[contains(@class,'android.widget.EditText')])[2]
```

The above for second element.

Comment: I tried your method , but i am getting this error :-  org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: android.support.test.uiautomator.StaleObjectException

Comment: @AndroidFindBy(xpath = "//*[@class='android.widget.EditText']")
 public WebElement Mobile;

Comment: Please help me with this

Comment: Like This @AndroidFindBy(xpath = "//*[contains@class='android.widget.EditText']")

Comment: @AndroidFindBy(xpath = "//*[contains(@class,'android.widget.EditText')])")
 public WebElement Mobile;

Comment: It's not working , how do we handle these elements when there is almost nothing to locate

Answer (score 0):

I tried this way of finding element:

List name = driver.findElements(By.xpath("android.widget.EditText"));
        name.get(0).click();

But i am getting bellow error:-
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Please let me know what is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I found one of my dynamic element through this method :-

findElementByXPath("//android.widget.FrameLayout[@index='0']/android.widget.EditText[@index='0']")

but for second element also , these details are same, so if i am putting same method to find  second element , it search the first one only.

Than i printed size of the element with this find method

Size is coming like this

(996, 89)

Please let me know how can i find second element , because it has same details.